# Using TestContext for the TestMethod Datasource

Tags: c#, xml, automation, mstest

Using MSTest, does anyone know how I can read XML attributes via a TestContext object?

I have the following code:

```
protected TestContext testContext;
public TestContext TestContext
{
    get { return this.testContext; }
    set { this.testContext = value; }
}

[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("\\TestData\\MyXML.xml")]
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "|DataDirectory|\\TestData\\MyXML.xml", "Client", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]

public void ReadMyXMLFile()
{
       TestContext.DataRow["Client"].ToString()
}
```

This is OK as I can retrieve all clients.  But what if, in my XML, I have attributes that I wish to filter out?  For example, in my existing XML I have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<Clients>
  <Client valid="true">
    <ClientName>John</ClientName>
    <ClientID>123</ClientID>
  </Client>
  <Client valid="false">
    <ClientName>Rufus</ClientName>
    <ClientID>564</ClientID>
  </Client>
</Clients>
```

So using the DataSource and the TextContext object is there any way I can filter out clients where the valid attribute=true?

Thank you.